# Is there a way to copy section in orbeon?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

We have a very big section in one form and want it in other forms with some modifications. Can't keep it in the library because section required some modifications before using it in another form. Is there a good way to copy the section from one form to another form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing, and Orbeon Forms 2017.1, to copy a section from form A to form B, you need to edit the source of form A, copy the source for the section, open form B, edit the source, and paste the section in the appropriate place.

However, we do have [request for enhancement #1839](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1839) that covers allowing cut-copy-paste across forms, which as noted in the issue, might not even be super hard to implement.

Comment: This is now implemented and will be in Orbeon Forms 2020.1.